# Splitting all IP:port values with a comma using VIM

Tags: vim

I have a datafile that constains log entries that looks as follows:

```
  2011-08-17,12:01:01.813,0.000,UDP,82.117.234.33:23989,147.32.86.165:12114,INT,0,1,71,1,Background
  2011-08-17,12:01:01.813,0.075,UDP,147.32.84.118:1153,91.225.21.243:35691,INT,0,1,143,1,Background
  2011-08-17,12:01:01.813,0.000,UDP,147.32.86.165:12114,82.117.234.33:23989,INT,0,1,61,1,Background
  2011-08-17,12:01:01.816,1.999,UDP,119.30.39.65:42343,147.32.84.229:13363,INT,0,4,1442,1,Background
  2011-08-17,12:01:01.816,1.999,UDP,147.32.84.229:13363,119.30.39.65:42343,INT,0,4,244,1,Background
  ...
```

I want to parse this with Pandas, and also obtain all port-values as seperate columns. To do this, all IP:port entries `82.117.234.33:23989` should be transformed to `82.117.234.33,23989`. Is this possible in VIM?

I know that I could use the following command `%s/:/,/gc` to replace all `:` values with commas, but that would break my timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groups of digits can be matched by using `\d\+`:

```
%s/\(\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\):\(\d\+\),/\1,\2,/g
```

Comment: Hmm I am getting a Pattern not found error, are you sure this is the correct expression?

Comment: @AlfonsIngomar yes, found 10 matches

Comment: Vimgolf: `:%s/\v\d+%(\.\d+){3}\zs:\ze\d+,/,/g`